# Standardized Exam for Statistics?

Tags: exams, statistics

I have been trying to find a standardized exam for statistics, but have not had any luck. For example, there is an AP statistics exam for high schoolers to take, but I am looking for something that graduating undergraduates would take as a sort of exit exam to test proficiency. Neither is the Mathematics GRE Subject Test what I am looking for, since it is mostly about pure math and not specifically statistical methods. Any ideas?

Comment: A standardized statistics test for undergraduates is too broad.  What population of students are you looking to test proficiency for?  Math majors, nursing students, etc?

Comment: The students whose proficiency I'm looking to test are statistics majors. I realize not every university has such a major, but we have recently added it.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the [actuarial exams](http://www.beanactuary.org/exams/preliminary/?fa=preliminary-exams) emphasize statistics and probability, specifically SOA Exam P and CAS exam S. This might be too broad or too specific, but they are indeed standardized exams which test more-advanced statistical knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice group of general stat final exams at UNC Charlotte, they may be just what you are looking for!

http://math.uncc.edu/undergraduate-programs/course-outlines-and-past-common-final-exams/stat-1222-introduction-statistics

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Most people are not going to follow an external link unless you describe what is to be found and how it answers the question.

Comment: These are final exams for a statistic course at UNC Charlotte. They are the type of questions that would be featured in statistics "exit exams" and if you know all the stuff in the exams, you would be considered at the very least proficient in the subject.

Answer (score 0):

There are the so-called [DSST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSST_(standardized_test)) tests.  Syllabus and sample questions can be found [here](http://getcollegecredit.com/assets/pdf/dsst_fact_sheets/DSST_PRINCIPLES_OF_STATISTICS_2016-2017_Fact_Sheet.pdf).  These exams are designed to give students college credit and according to Wikipedia "are comparable to the final or end-of-course examinations in undergraduate college courses".